# How to write conditional step with boolean parameter in jenkins scripted pipeline job?

Tags: if-statement, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

This condition in my script always gets evaluated as **true** and prints "Yes equal - running the stage"

```
stage('test cond'){  
    if(env.BUILD_TESTING2 == true){  
        echo "Yes equal - running the stage"
    } else {
        echo "Not equal - skipping the stage"
    }
}
```

Even if I start the build by setting env.BUILD_TESTING2 = **false** it still enters the condition and prints "Yes equal - running the stage".

I also tried this syntax:

```
stage('test cond'){  
    if(env.BUILD_TESTING2){  
        echo "Yes equal - running the stage"
    } else {
        echo "Not equal - skipping the stage"
    }
}
```

But it also still always gets evaluated as **true**.

How can I write a conditional step with boolean parameter in Jenkins scripted pipeline ?

Comment: I think you are running into a similar issue listed here - https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-46552. Setting it to false is actually setting it as a string instead of a boolean so anything not false or null is being evaluated to true.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to convert this environment variable (of type string) to boolean using toBoolean() function:

```
stage('test cond'){  
    if(env.BUILD_TESTING2.toBoolean()){  
        echo "Yes equal - running the stage"
    } else {
        echo "Not equal - skipping the stage"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this syntax work with the `steps { }` syntax?

Answer (score 18):

Better reference parameters by params instead of env, this way they have the correct object type. So use:

```
stage('test cond') {
    if(params.BUILD_TESTING2) {
        echo "Yes equal - running the stage"
    } else {
        echo "Not equal - skipping the stage"
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the right answer if you're using Boolean type Jenkins build parameters. Proof is in the link provided by @ben5556 https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-46552

Comment: Yeah but that wasn't the question. I upvote though since it is good practice.

Comment: Thanks @Davis8988. The question was "How can I write a conditional step with boolean parameter in Jenkins scripted pipeline?" The answer is "reference the parameter by params instead of env in your conditional step"

Answer (score 11):

If you're using booleanParam, the cleanest way that I know is to use [when](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) directive with expression.

```
stage('test cond') {
     when { expression { return params.BUILD_TESTING2 } }
     steps {
        sh 'echo "running the stage"'
    }
}
```